# Android Volley HTTP Get request has a strange response?

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

## Problem description

I'm using Volley for an HTTP Request, but something pretty strange just happened.

If I check the webpage myself that the GET request is fetching, it is in a correct JSON format.

`{ data: [...] }`for example.

However, when Volley fetches it, the response is something like this:

`473858840819 { data: [...] }}`

It has a random number at the front and an extra bracket in the end. I double checked and debugged, and it only happens when Volley requests the page. Any ideas?

My dirty fix is to check if there's a number, and if so, delete the number and bracket... However I'd like to fix this issue better.

Is it because of the encoding or something?

---

## Android Volley Code

```
private void doFetch(String url)
{
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    // The really dirty fix I want to eliminate....
                    if(!(response.charAt(0)+"").equals("{"))
                    {
                        // Remove number at front                             // Remove excess } at the end
                        response = response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.length()-1);
                    }

                    // Save to SharedPreferences cache
                    saveToCache(response);

                    // Convert to json and display to UI
                    convertJson(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: There are two ways to look at it. First it might be your server returning different response. Secondly somwhere in you android code should be the issue. Paste some logs from android for the request response and will check that.

Comment: @driftking9987 I added the code!

Comment: @Panther Volley never returns any errors. It's just converting the JSON is an issue since it's in an invalid format. Btw, I'm using the Forecast.io API.

Comment: Why don't you use `JsonRequest`?

Comment: The java code looks good to me. You are not really doing anything there. What about PHP code? Is there anything?

Comment: The android code looks good. If thats a public url, please can you provide it.

Comment: JSONRequest: fair point, didn't know that existed. Thanks for the heads up!
PHP code: it's the forecast.io API. Let me make a new API key just for testing and share the link here. => https://api.forecast.io/forecast/305c4dbeca10d8195fc37ace82149db5/37.8267,-122.423
Also I should mention that this only happened since today, without changing code. Yesterday it didn't do this, strangely enough.

Comment: The link which you provided is the final url which you are calling and I can't see any irregularity in the JSON over there. I'll be more interested in seeing the PHP code as that will explain the current situation.

Comment: @driftking9987 I understand but I don't have access to any PHP code unfortunately, since it is not my API. I'll try to debug more and see if I can find anything else that might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with JSON why don't you create a JsonObjectRequest rather than StringRequest. Try this :

```
public void doFetch(String url) {

    JsonObjectRequest getJsonRequest;

    getJsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null, 
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // The really dirty fix I want to eliminate....
                if(!(response.charAt(0)+"").equals("{"))
                {
                    // Remove number at front                             // Remove excess } at the end
                    response = response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.length()-1);
                }

                // Save to SharedPreferences cache
                saveToCache(response);

                // Convert to json and display to UI
                convertJson(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley Error Message : ", error);
            }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(getJsonRequest);
}
```

Comment: I guess the response is not valid JSONObject, so you get exception and onErrorResponse will be called instead.